# body border-top does not extend beyond viewport

Tags: css, border, viewport

I need a purple line along the top of the site. Instead of using an image I'm using the `border-top` property on the body.  This works in full view but when I resize the browser window the purple line appears only in the viewport, when I scroll to the right I get a white space.  [Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K5zVq/3/) so you can see what I mean.  I've tried `width: 100%` on both the body and the container, but to no avail.  Can someone suggest ways to accomplish what I need?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know your documents width then you can specify a min-width.

```
body { min-width: 960px; }
```

Comment: Most suggestions worked in my case. I choose this one because it 'played' best with the rest of my styles :)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is the best way to accomplish it, but you can add `position: absolute;` to the body. This may have some undesired side effects.

Answer (score 0):

Try the body border hack :)

http://css-tricks.com/558-body-border/

Designed for fixed position but should work for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `display: inline-block;` to both `body` and `container` also worked. See http://jsfiddle.net/K5zVq/16/.

Answer (score 0):

A secondary answer, related to skoh-fley's though maybe with less consequences, is to add `float: left` to the `body`: http://jsfiddle.net/K5zVq/20/. Though I think I would lean toward my first answer posted here (though you know your situation better than I).